# Update Razor variable in foreach using button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Okay, so after a lot of searching around I haven't really found an answer to my problem. I am currently working on a page who's main purpose is to display articles on the main page.

I got the code down to display all the articles, but what I really want is to only display say the 6 first articles in the foreach and then the user can chose to increase the display count by 6 each time he/she clicks the "Show more articles" button.

I am using `@foreach (var item in Model.Take(displayedArticles))`, where `var displayedArticles = 6;`

Is there a way for the user to increase this counter by clicking a "Show more" button? I am having some issues.

My current code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h2 class="page-header">Index</h2>

@{
    var displayedArticles = 6;
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Take(displayedArticles))
{
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) </h2>
        <div id="textContent">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div class="col-lg-12" >
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Show more articles" id="showMore" onclick="@(displayedArticles+=6)" style="width: 100%"/> 
</div>
```

I have tried to do this in JQuery, and it did log the updated value to the console, but it did not update the Razor foreach.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Just changing the value of a javascript variable in the client has no affect on whats already been rendered. You need to use ajax to call the controller and return new a partial view containing the 'next articles' and update the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need AJAX. Something as simple as:

```
$('#showMore').click(function () {
    $.get('Article/ShowMore', function (html) {
        $('.col-lg-4').append(html);
    });
});
```

That's the gist of it. Now in your controller, you'll send back an `ActionResult` that points to a partial. The rendered partial will then get injected into your page.